# Finding an upper bound and limit for the nested square root sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to solve the following problem from [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Echparkin/gre/Week6.pdf):

> **Problem 2.** Fix $x > 0$. Give a rigorous meaning to $\sqrt {x + \sqrt {x +\sqrt {x + \ldots}}}$ by proving that the sequence
> $$a_0 = \sqrt x, \ a_n = \sqrt {x + a_{n-1}}, \ n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$$
> converges and finding the limit. What happens as $x \rightarrow 0$?

I'm thinking of using the monotone convergence theorem. I can show that the terms of the sequence are increasing by simple induction. But I'm not sure how to come up with an upper for the sequence for any $x > 0$. Is there any generic strategy to find upper bounds of such sequences. Secondly, I'm not sure how to explicitly find the limit even after proving that the sequence converges.

Comment: To find a bound, it is often useful to determine the candidate values for the limit (*if* the sequence converges, *then* the limit must be ...). Have you an idea how to do that?

Comment: It should be $a_0=\sqrt{x}$. Assuming $x> \frac{1}{4}$ the map $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ given by $f(t)=\sqrt{x+t}$ is a contraction since $f$ is concave and $f'(0)<1$, hence $a_n=f^{(n)}(x)$ converges to the only fixed point of $f$, given by $\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{1+4x}\right)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I was thinking if we could take the limit on both sides of the equation $a_n = \sqrt{x + a_{n-1}}$ that is $a = \sqrt{x + a}$ and then evaluate $a$, but I'm not sure which theorem allows us to take the limit on both sides as such.

Comment: Assuming $x\in\left(0,\frac{1}{4}\right]$ we have that $f(t)=\sqrt{x+t}$, over the interval $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{1+4x})\right)$, is increasing, concave, $\geq t$ and $\leq\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{1+4x})$, so the limit still is $\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{1+4x}\right)$.

Comment: The function $f \colon t \mapsto \sqrt{x + t}$ is continuous. Thus if the limit exists, the value at the limit is the limit of the values at the points of the sequence. And we found that if the limit exists, it must be a fixed point of $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer That looks like an interesting theorem! Could you point me to a proof? I think I have seen it somewhere but I can't recall it (i.e., for continuous functions the limit of the sequence is a fixed point).

Comment: It's basically just an application of the definition of continuity. Say we have a sequence with some starting value $x_0$, and the recurrence $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ with continuous $f$ (and the closure of the range of $f$ contained in the domain, to be sure all compositions and limiting operations are well-defined). Suppose that $x_n \to L$. Since $x_n$ lies in the range of $f$ for all $n \geqslant 1$ it follows that $L$ is in the domain of $f$. Continuity of $f$ says $f(L) = \lim f(x_n)$. But $f(x_n) = x_{n+1} \to L$, hence $f(L) = L$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I was reviewing your last comment and I have a small question: if $x_n$ lies in the range of $f$ for all $n \geq 1$ why exactly does it follow that $L$ is in the domain of $f$?

Comment: Since $x_n \to L$ it follows that $L$ lies in the closure of the range of $f$. I made the assumption that this closure is contained in the domain specifically for the purpose of dealing with the limiting.